# Find the value of $\sum_{i=0}^n{\ell+i\choose i}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How to find the $\sum_{i=0}^n{\ell+i\choose i}$. I'd tried several binomial series, but cannot be work. Also does it have a combinatoric intuitive explanation?

Comment: There is no identity here.  An identity has an equal sign in it.  What are you trying to prove?

Comment: What is the _identity_ that you wish to prove? The expression you have written is _not_ an identity.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Just editted. I was thinking that there is an identity..

Comment: Try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity. Or you can write out a few terms and induct. Hint: It's equal to one binomial, something choose $n$.

Comment: An alternative hint: try using the diagonals of Pascal's triangle

Comment: @marlasca23 Hockey stick gets its name from the diagonal of Pascal's triangle. They are the same thing, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the image

[image]

The famous demonstration of the hockey stick identity. With your sum, we can start at $\binom{\ell}{0}$ and take a walk down the diagonal for $n$ terms (its the mirror image of the above picture). By the hockey stick identity, this is simply $\binom{n+\ell +1}{n}$. This is because the last term is $\binom{\ell +n}{n}$, then we go to the next row, to $\binom{\ell +n+1}{n}$ for the sum.